# SalesForce's URL for Kafka provider

Tags: apache-kafka, salesforce, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to determine the URL for SalesForce as it relates to setting up a Kafka Provider. I'm using `Bayeux` client that needs a URL to SalesForce for connection:

```
new KafkaOptions(new Uri(""));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What library does `KafkaOptions` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using [this Kafka library](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net#examples), which has nothing to do with Salesforce, but you give it a string of your Kafka broker addresses, as shown in the examples there.

Note: That library doesn't look actively maintained and Kafka is not an http protocol so putting `http://server:9092` doesn't make sense...

You might want to checkout [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) instead.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation but, does this works with SalesForce Stream API?

Comment: If you can import any .NET library, then yes, but you're not going to be giving any Salesforce URI to the KafkaOptions anyway

Comment: Understood...this should be the kafka brokers URL. What I can't seems to understand is if I"m using the `Bayeux` client surely there must be an endpoint on the SalesForce side that gets called to subscribe to the topic there . Secondly the URL to get an OAUTH access token from SalesForce seems sparse and not specific...thoughts?

Comment: I'm only here for the Kafka tag, not Salesforce, so I'm not sure I understand the question. But with any API, you would get data from one place, generate a Kafka payload and send it to Kafka, or vice versa, consume Kafka records and push them to your external API... Regarding this Bayeux thing, it sounds like it's HTTP based, which again, I mentioned Kafka is not

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this helps, but you can try a Kafka Connect plugin https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-salesforce/index.html